# Change Date Value when Time Changes from 23:59 to 0:00 (or similar).

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have written code to read in data sets that look like this:

```
Started 4/1/2015 23:57  
Trimmed 0
Recording IBI       
HR, Time, Value
-----------------------
20, 23:57:00, OK
25, 23:58:00, OK
15, 23:59:00, OK
15, 00:00:00, OK
15, 00:01:00, OK
20, 00:02:00, OK
```

The start date is only listed once, which I pull and plug into a date column. The data runs continuously, even if the rows run for what amounts to multiple days without demarcation of when the date should change. I want a command to change the date when time switches from 23:59 to 0:00 (or similar leaps that generally convey the next day has started). I have tried different versions of this:

```
df$date <- ifelse(df$time > lag(df$time, n=1),
                    paste(as.Date(lag(df$date, n=1), format="%Y-%m-%d")),
                    paste(as.Date(lag(df$date, n=1), format="%Y-%m-%d")+1))
```

But this only changes the single cell in the row where the day switches, 
and not all of the following rows until the date should switch again (only row 4 in the example and not rows 5 and 6. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cumsum` to count the number of time the clock "rolls over":

```
dat$date <-  c(Started= as.Date("4/1/2015 23:57", "%d/%m/%Y") ) + 
                                                cumsum(dat$Time == "00:00:00")

dat
  HR     Time Value       date
1 20 23:57:00    OK 2015-01-04
2 25 23:58:00    OK 2015-01-04
3 15 23:59:00    OK 2015-01-04
4 15 00:00:00    OK 2015-01-05
5 15 00:01:00    OK 2015-01-05
6 20 00:02:00    OK 2015-01-05
```

Or if you might miss some of the midnights you could `cumsum` on the number of times the differences in leading digits of the Time item go negative.